# Using arrow keys

Tags: java, swing, input, keyboard

I am trying to get my arrow key to move smoothly. For the most part the code works, however, when the arrow key is pressed for the first time it jumps to the top left corner of the jpanel and then does what I want it to. How can I get it to stop jumping on the first arrow push?

Thanks for any help.

```
public class myJPanel0 extends JPanel implements KeyListener
   //This panel will contain the game 
{ 
    JButton menu;
Image myImage;
Graphics g;
myJPanel1 p1;
JButton lion = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/lion.jpg"));  
int x =100;
int y = 100;
     public myJPanel0(myJPanel1 informedp1)
     {
      super();
      setLayout(null);
      p1 = informedp1;
      setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
      menu = new JButton("Menu");
   //   lion.setSize(49,49);
      lion.setBounds(296,355,49,80);
      menu.setBounds(new Rectangle(250,5,80,30));
      add(menu);
      add(lion);

      setFocusable(true);
  addKeyListener(this);



     }
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    if(p1.myImage1 == 1)
    {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
        Image myImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/snow.jpg");//Place      holder for now, we can come up with our own image.
    g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0,680,460, this); 
    requestFocusInWindow();
    }else if(p1.myImage1 == 2) 
       {
           super.paintComponent(g); 
           Image myImage =    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/grass.jpg");//Place holder for now, we can come up with our own image.
           g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0,680,460, this);  
           requestFocusInWindow();
       }
    else{
           super.paintComponent(g); 
           Image myImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/stone.jpg");//Place holder for now, we can come up with our own image.
           g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0,680,460, this); 
           requestFocusInWindow();
       }
      }
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) 
  {
System.out.println("Key pressed");
int kk = evt.getKeyCode();
if(kk ==  evt.VK_LEFT) {x=x-49;} 
else if(kk ==  evt.VK_RIGHT) {x=x+49;}
else if(kk ==  evt.VK_UP) {y=y-50;}
else if(kk ==  evt.VK_DOWN) {y=y+50;}
lion.setBounds(x,y,45,75);
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {  }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {  }
       }
```

Comment: `however, when the arrow key is pressed for the first time it jumps to the top left corner of the jpanel` Who is it ? 5 people and it ?

Comment: It would be a jbutton

Comment: You are trying to move a `JButton` using arrows ? Why not a `JLabel` ?? :-/

Comment: Better yet don't use a null layout and don't try to move any JComponent around on its parent. Use painting to draw an image and move the image coordinates around.

Comment: What difference would it make if its a label or a button?

Comment: @user1566796, Don't use a KeyListener. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in next: at start you set `lion.setBounds(296,355,49,80);`
Position of that object is **296,355**, but when you press keys  at first you use `int x =100;
int y = 100;`, Because of that you have that effect. Change x and y to `int x = 296;
int y = 355;` and it will be work.